# Azure coreos in sleeping mode

Tags: node.js, azure, bookshelf.js

I am using Coreos for my container hosted in the Azure, and I have a nodejs app connected to external mysql database using bookshelfjs/knexjs.

The problem is after sometime the app will go into sleeping mode, when I make first request it will not response, but after third retry it is successful.

It is because of Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreOS hosted on Azure VM is similar with Azure WebApp as the thread https://serverfault.com/questions/620788/does-enabling-always-on-in-a-ms-azure-website-make-it-more-expensive said.

For balancing the Azure resource, Azure will unloads your idle resource until the first ping or request.

So if you want to keep your CoreOS always works, you can try to trigger a job that request the application with a suitable time interval, or you can try to configure an AlwaysOn Availability Groups for your CoreOS VMs.